# sockets sniffer

Tags: sockets, sniffer

Does someone know of a good .Net socket sniffer?
I'm trying to build an IM sniffer that can show the Unicode chars correctly.

TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SharpPCap](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpPcap.aspx)

Comment: +1, I've used SharpPcap before and it really is an awesome library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) library. Just create a wrapper in .NET for the unmanaged code.

Comment: Which is exactly what SharpPcap does for you :).

Comment: That's also what Pcap.Net does (and almost all other packet capture frameworks also do).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com).